# aapt_rules.txt not found: libGDX project on IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx, proguard

I'm facing this problem when I try to build a project for which I've added support for proguard in my android/build.gradle file as follows:

```
// Proguard configuration
buildTypes {
    release {
        //minifyEnabled true will turn proguard ON
        minifyEnabled true
        //proguardFiles let you add your own proguard rules ('proguard-project.txt') in this case, as its already created by gdx-setup
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
```

I've no proguard-android.txt file, but I do have a proguard-project.txt file within the same android module directory with the following text:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.parentDir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-verbose

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.utils.Box2DBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget*
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreetypeBuild

-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.android.AndroidControllers

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {
   <init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context, java.lang.Object, com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
}

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
   boolean contactFilter(long, long);
   void    beginContact(long);
   void    endContact(long);
   void    preSolve(long, long);
   void    postSolve(long, long);
   boolean reportFixture(long);
   float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
}
```

The error I get is this:

> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /home/.../Desktop/Idea/.../android/build/intermediates/proguard-rules/release/aapt_rules.txt
>   (No such file or directory)

I've seen other's problem is that they have an empty proguard rules file, but this is clearly not the case.

Any ideas on how I could debug this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found to this problem was to **delete the android/build directory inside my project altogether**, before "Invalidate Cache/Restart..." in the File menu. I've tried several times that menu option before without deleting the android/build directory and it made no difference at all.

Rebuilding the project didn't work either despite having the checkbox "Clean project on rebuild" enabled, so it seems that sometimes to get a clean project in IntelliJ Idea you have to do it by yourself.